# Response 400 'Bad Request' when trying to get access token from Reddit API

Tags: python, reddit

I'm trying to use the reddit API to pull text data for a machine learning project, but I can't get the OAuth access token. Instead of responding with the access token, the response just says bad request.

Here's my code:

```
import requests

auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('*****', '****')

data = {'grant_type':'password',
        'username' : '*****',
        'password':'******'}

headers = {'User Agent': 'win64 : **** v1.0.0 by /u/*****'}

res = requests.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', auth=auth, data=data, headers=headers)

print(res)
```

I've triple checked the personal use script and secret, and so I'm struggling to think of what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Your "User Agent" header should be "User-Agent"

Comment: Wow. Yes that did it. Thanks!